# Showing that $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, continuity

So, I want to prove a particular convergence result using the Uniform Limit Theorem, which is stated below:

> **Uniform Limit Theorem:** Let $f_n: X \to Y$ be a sequence of continuous functions from a topological space $X$ to a metrizable space $Y$. If $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a function $f: X \to Y$, then $f$ is continuous.

Now, the result I want to prove is as follows:

> **Claim:** Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $Y$ be a metrizable space (with metric $d$). Also, let $f_n :X \to Y$ be a sequence of continuous functions, and let $x_n$ be a sequence of points in $X$ converging to $x$. If the sequence $(f_n)$ of functions converges uniformly to $f$, then $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$.

**Proof Attempt:** Consider the point $f(x)$ in $Y$, and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $f(x)$. We wish to show that there is an integer $M$ such that $f_n(x_n) \in U$ for all $n > M$. Choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that $B(f(x), \epsilon) \subset U$. Also, we see that $B(f(x), \epsilon/4) \subset B(f(x), \epsilon) \subset U$. We note that by the uniform limit theorem, we may conclude that $f$ is continuous. Thus, since $x_n \to x$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ by the continuity of $f$.

This along with the fact that $B(f(x), \epsilon/4)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$ implies that there is an integer $N_1$ such that $$f(x_n) \in B(f(x), \epsilon/4) \ \text{for all} \ \ n > N_1 \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Now, we note that because $f_n \to f$ uniformly, there is an integer $N_2$ such that $$ f_n(t) \in B(f(t), \epsilon/4) \ \ \text{for all} \ n> N_2 \ \ \text{and all} \ t \in X \ \ (2)$$

Now, fix $r > \max\{N_1, N_2\} = M$. Since $x_r \in X$, it follows by $(2)$ that $f_r(x_r) \in B(f(x_r), \epsilon/4)$. In other words, $d(f_r(x_r), f(x_r)) < \epsilon/4$. Additionally, it follows by $(1)$ that $d(f(x_r), f(x)) < \epsilon/4$. So, invoking the triangle inequality, we see that $$d(f_r(x_r), f(x)) \leq d(f_r(x_r), f(x_r)) + d(f(x_r), f(x)) < \epsilon/2$$
This shows that $f_r(x_r) \in B(f(x), \epsilon) \subset U$. Since $r > M$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f_n(x_n) \in U$ for all $n > M$, as desired.

Is this a correct proof, or have I perhaps overlooked or misused particular details? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: That's all you need, it highlights how powerful uniform convergence is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Your proof is correct.